# UIkit Grid gutter not shown

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, getuikit

I have been trying out UIkit recently, but still very new to it. I could not get the grids to work as expected even after a lot of time and searches on google.

Grid gutters are not there.

This is the simplified code.

```html
<div class="uk-container">
  <div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-1-2 uk-panel uk-panel-box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum nulla impedit quaerat adipisci aliquid nam, nobis voluptatum incidunt maiores pariatur blanditiis laboriosam repellendus rem molestiae corporis recusandae tempore consequatur. Iure!</div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-2 uk-panel uk-panel-box">Vel illo molestiae excepturi provident aspernatur rerum explicabo inventore. Quam id sed cumque provident explicabo esse, quaerat laborum perferendis? Impedit explicabo deleniti veniam nostrum tempora reiciendis nam! Repellat, fugit, eum.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a snapshot of the result.

[image]

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put panel classes on columns, add another div inside column div.

```
<div class="uk-container">
<div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
        <div class="uk-panel">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
        <div class="uk-panel">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Above example is taken from the docs.